# Why matlab returns wrong answer

Tags: matlab

I want to do some calculations on my images. I use Matlab, but it returns the wrong answer. I don't know why.

Here is my file:

```
    function [ newImage ] = Run( file )

info = geotiffinfo(file);
[bands,R1]=geotiffread(file);



imageSize=size(bands);

result=nan(imageSize(1),imageSize(2),7);

for i=100:105

    for j=100:105

       disp(strcat('Pixel ',sprintf('[%d,%d] of [%d,%d]',imageSize(1),imageSize(2), i,j)));
       b7=bands(i,i,5);
       b6=bands(i,i,4);
       b5=bands(i,i,3);
       b4=bands(i,i,2);
       b3=bands(i,i,1);

       %ndvi 7-4/7+4
       result(i,j,1)= (b7-b4)/(b7+b4);
       %NDI45 5-4/5+4
       result(i,j,2)= (b5-b4)/(b5+b4);
       %MTCI 6-5/5-4
       result(i,j,3)= (b6-b5)/(b5-b4);
       %MCARI [(B5 - B4) - 0.2(B5- B3)] * (B5 - B4)
       result(i,j,4)= ((b5-b4)-(0.2*(b5-b3)))*(b5-b4);
       %GNDVI 7-3/7+3
       result(i,j,4)= (b7-b3)/(b7+b3);
       %PSSR 7/4
       result(i,j,5)= (b7)/(b4);
       %S2REP 705 + 35 *((((B7 + B4)/2) - B5)/(B6 - B5))
       result(i,j,6)= 705 + 35 *((((b7 + b4)/2) - b5)/(b6 - b5));
       %IRECI 7-4/(5/6)
        result(i,j,7)=(b7-b4)/(b5/b6);



    end 
end


geotiffwrite('D:\SazmanJangalha\ref\result.tif', result, R1,  ...
       'GeoKeyDirectoryTag', info.GeoTIFFTags.GeoKeyDirectoryTag);
end
```

I simply run these commands and it returns the wrong answers:

```
     result(i,j,7)

ans =

     0

K>> b7-b4

ans =

      0

K>> b7

b7 =

    679

K>> b4

b4 =

   1149

K>> b7-b4

ans =

      0
```

It seems like the results are rounded. Why?

Comment: What is the type of `bands`?

Comment: @beaker it is unit16

Comment: What do you think happens when you subtract a larger, *unsigned* integer from a smaller, *unsigned* integer?

Comment: @excaza wow..how I am silly.. It cant save negative values..right?How can convert it to double or thing like that?

Comment: See: [numeric types](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/numeric-types.html). I'd caution against just willy-nilly changing types. Think of the operations you're performing, the consequences a type change could cause, and pick a type appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because usually images are stored using `UINT8` or `UINT16`.
The solution would be to convert the data into `double` or `single`.

Put the following line:

```
bands = double(bands);
```

And it should work.

Comment: Or a signed integer... Blindly converting to a floating point data type when your program is developed assuming integer operations is a great way to open oneself up to undesired behavior.

Comment: @excaza, I agree with all you written. Yet what I wrote will direct the OP to the "Tricky" point.

Comment: He was directed to the "tricky" part an hour before you posted your answer.